# In scala multiple inheritance, how to resolve conflicting methods with same signature but different return type?

Tags: scala, multiple-inheritance, traits

Consider the code below:

```
trait A {
  def work = { "x" }
}

trait B {
  def work = { 1 }
}

class C extends A with B {
  override def work = super[A].work
}
```

Class `C` won't compile in scala 2.10, because of "overriding method work in trait A of type => String; method work has incompatible type".

How to choose one specific method?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no way to do that. The `super[A].work` way works only if `A` and `B` have the same return types.

Consider this:

```
class D extends B

....

val test: List[B] = List(new C(), new D())
test.map(b => b.work) //oops - C returns a String, D returns an Int
```

Answer (score 6):

Scala simply prevents you from mixing `A` and `B` together if they declare a method with the same name and incompatible signature.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do that.

Look at this piece of code:

```
val c = new C
val a: A = c
val b: B = c
```

There is no way that *both* of these lines could work:

```
val s: String = a.work
val i: Int = b.work
```

If we allowed such code to compile, one of these assignments would have to throw a `ClassCastException` or fail in another way. So, it simply isn't possible to resolve such conflict.

I guess you have to workaround this with some form of delegation, maybe something like this:

```
class C extends A {
  def toB = new B {
    //implement B methods by somehow delegating them to C instance
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't do that in Scala.

The way to work this around is to use the traits as collaborators

```
trait A {
  def work = { "x" }
}

trait B {
  def work = { 1 }
}

class C {
  val a = new A { }
  val b = new B { }

  a.work
  b.work
}
```