# How can I resolve conflicting actor systems while testing akka-http and akka actors at the same spec file?

Tags: scala, testing, akka, akka-http, akka-actor

I have a `Route` defined using akka-http that uses an actor inside to send messages.
My route looks like this:

```scala
      path("entity") {
        post {
          entity(as[Enrtity]) {
            entity =>
              val result: Future[Message] = mainActor.ask {
                ref: akka.actor.typed.ActorRef[Message] =>
                  Message(
                    entity = entity,
                    replyRef = ref
                  )
              }
              complete("OK")
          }
        }
      }
```

My test spec:

```scala
class APITest
    extends ScalaTestWithActorTestKit(ManualTime.config)
    with ScalatestRouteTest
    with AnyWordSpecLike {
      val manualTime: ManualTime = ManualTime()
     // my tests here ...
}
```

Compiling the test fails since there are conflicting actor systems:

```
class APITest inherits conflicting members:
[error]   implicit def system: akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem[Nothing] (defined in class ActorTestKitBase) and
[error]   implicit val system: akka.actor.ActorSystem (defined in trait RouteTest)
```

Overriding the actor system doesn't help either since the inherited actor systems are of both typed and untyped ones. 
How can I resolve this easily?

**Update:**

This is related to [conflicting inherited members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153088/in-scala-multiple-inheritance-how-to-resolve-conflicting-methods-with-same-sign) with different types, but we might be able to solve what I want to achieve in this context differently.

Comment: `ScalaTestWithActorTestKit` and `ScalatestRouteTest` are not compatible. If you do not really need `ScalaTestWithActorTestKit`, maybe you can remove it?

Answer (score 0):

I spent a little time here while moving over to typed. For anyone still looking, there's a nice hint at https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/akka-http-quickstart-scala/testing-routes.html

```scala
// the Akka HTTP route testkit does not yet support a typed actor system (https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/2036)
// so we have to adapt for now
lazy val testKit = ActorTestKit()
implicit def typedSystem = testKit.system
override def createActorSystem(): akka.actor.ActorSystem =
  testKit.system.classicSystem
```

Looking at the first comment at https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/2036 it notes

> Perhaps just a docs addition to show that you don't need to use the ActorTestKit from Akka Typed and can just use TestProbes e.g. https://gist.github.com/chbatey/964b80adc2cd124fa4bf4624927b5be0

or `val probe = TestProbe[Ping]()` > `val probe = testKit.createTestProbe[Ping]()`